# Stretchy header tableView in Swift

Tags: uitableview, scroll, swift3

I am new to Swift.
Now , I'm trying to make a try about Stretchy header in tableView which is something like “If you scroll to see more cells of tableView and the tableView will extend and cover the view top of the tableView; In contrast , it will compress in to a little size”.

Reference of [this gitHub project](https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView)

But, I have no idea how to implement in Swift .. can somebody teach me or tell me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this in swift using this pod**

just [install it](https://github.com/y-hryk/StretchHeader)

```
 pod 'StretchHeader'
```

for understanding in depth see [this](https://blog.frozenfirestudios.com/how-to-add-a-stretchy-flair-to-your-uicollectionview-e403822e0f33#.osbvilx0n) tutorial...